# Vite css @import from package, "missing specifier" when using file path

Tags: node.js, svelte, vite, sveltekit

I'm currently trying to learn how to use sveltekit, and I'm having trouble with importing css from the @catppuccin/style package.

```css
@import "@catppuccin/palette/css/catppuccin.css";
```

returns with `[postcss] Missing "./css/catppuccin.css" specifier in "@catppuccin/palette" package`, but

```css
@import "@catppuccin/palette/style";
```

also errors with `Internal server error: Error while preprocessing /home/projects/sveltejs-kit-template-default-waw5r1/src/routes/+layout.svelte - Can't find stylesheet to import.`

None of this makes any sense, @catppuccin/palette/css/catppuccin.css does exist, and the package's package.json has style as an export to the same file. I get this error when importing from inside style tag in a svelte component.

Comment: Experiencing the same error ~ did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Vite and found out it was caused by how the imported module declares module/exports in its package.json.

The module in question:

```json
{
  "main": "./src/index.ts",
  "module": "./src/index.ts",
  "sideEffects": false,
  "exports": {
    "import": "./src/index.ts",
    "require": "./dist/index.umd.cjs"
  }
}
```

If `"exports"` is removed, then Vite is able to resolve the scss `@import`s correctly.

But since that is not an option in this case - because the "exports" bit guarantees that the package can be consumed in a `ts-node` environment - then the final solution (found here: https://github.com/vitejs/vite/discussions/2657#discussioncomment-5856909) was to also declare (specify) the possible scss exports.

```json
{
  "type": "module",
  "main": "./src/index.ts",
  "module": "./src/index.ts",
  "sideEffects": false,
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "import": "./src/index.ts",
      "require": "./dist/index.umd.cjs"
    },
    "./src/*.scss": {
      "import": "./src/*.scss",
      "require": "./src/*.scss"
    }
  }
}
```